# __weak and strong variable behaviour with blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

I am new to blocks and while reading over the internet I found that I must use weak variables to blocks, because blocks retains the variables. I am little confuse while using self with blocks. lets have an example:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (copy, nonatomic) void (^cyclicSelf1)();

-(IBAction)refferingSelf:(id)sender;
-(void)doSomethingLarge;
@end
```

Here I have a ViewController and it has declared block property with copy attribute. I don't want to make a retain cycle so I know when using self in the block I need to create weak object of self eg:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
```

What I want to make sure is my block executes on background thread and may be user hit back before it get finish. My block are performing some valuable task and I don't want that to loose. So I need self till the end of block. I did following in my implementation file:

```
-(IBAction)refferingSelf:(id)sender
{
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self; // Weak reference of block

    self.cyclicSelf1 = ^{

        //Strong reference to weak self to keep it till the end of block
        typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;    
        if(strongSelf){
            [strongSelf longRunningTask];//This takes about 8-10 seconds, Mean while I pop the view controller
        }
        [strongSelf executeSomeThingElse]; //strongSelf get nil here
    };
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), self.cyclicSelf1);
}
```

According to me, using `typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;` should create a strong reference of my `self` and when user hit back, self will still have one strong reference inside block until the scope get over.

Please help me to understand why this get crash? Why my strongSelf is not holding the object.

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: @NKorotkov strongSelf gets nil and the block is not able to ` [strongSelf executeSomeThingElse]`. The strongSelf is a strong pointer for self within block and it should not get nil until the end of block. Please let me know if I am wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your reference is not strong. Just add `__strong` directive like this:

```
__strong typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
```

Comment: That won't make any difference, as by default objects have strong type only until you specify __weak explicitly.

Comment: It doesn't matter, references are strong by default.

Comment: @LDNZh I've tried it and I take my words back. You were right. So typeof() applied to a weak referenced object actually returns __weak Type*, and not just Type*?

Comment: @NKorotkov Yes, it's also weak.

Comment: @LDNZh Thanks, it really worked. I wan't having any clue that typeof on an weak object will return weak type.

Answer (score 2):

I've found an answer. I was really curious myself, because your code seemed legit to me. The idea at least. So I've set up a similar project and experimented a little. The problem is this line:

```
typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
```

Change it to either

```
__strong typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
```

as suggested by @LDNZh or

```
typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
```

And your code will work.

**UPDATE:** Since this question shows up a lot I've made some changes to my example project. I'm making it available on [github](https://github.com/NKorotkov/BlockTest) for everyone for future reference.